# Exception AttributeError when starting roscore

Tags: ros-fuerte, roscore, ubuntu-precise, ubuntu

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I recently installed fuerte on Ubuntu 12.04 using the ros-fuerte debs.
Now when I run roscore I get the following error:

```
  Exception AttributeError: AttributeError("'_DummyThread' object has no attribute '_Thread__block'",) in <module 'threading' from '/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.pyc'> ignored
```

Is this normal? Things seem to work for the most part.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/34304/exception-attributeerror-when-starting-roscore/) by [Hordur](https://answers.ros.org/users/418/hordur/) on ROS Answers with karma: 544 on 2012-05-18

Post score: 4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is apparently a bug in Python as mentioned in following ticket and it shouldn't cause any harm.
https://code.ros.org/trac/ros/ticket/3950

---

Originally posted by [Hordur](https://answers.ros.org/users/418/hordur/) with karma: 544 on 2012-05-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 7